# Identity when Diagonalising Single-Particle Hamiltonian

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, second-quantization, tight-binding

Sorry the title is not precise; wasn't sure how to make it so (this is perhaps a straightforward question).

The following is an identity I see quite often when reading lecture notes about diagonalising single-particle, 1D (tight-binding) Hamiltonians (via changing to $k$-space): 
$$
\sum_j e^{i(k-k')ja} = N\delta_{k,k'}
$$
where as usual $a$ is the lattice constant, $N$ is the number of atoms and $j$ is the site index. [Example use](https://publish.illinois.edu/yubo-paul-yang/files/2015/03/Tight-Binding.pdf) (second to third line from equation 3).

First, I was wondering how to prove this (or at least why it makes physical sense). Second, I was wondering if this is just always true for any dimension. i.e. is the following identity true? Does it depend on the lattice?
$$
\sum_n e^{i(\vec k-\vec k')\cdot \vec R_n} = N\delta_{\vec k, \vec k'}
$$
where now $\vec R_n$ is the lattice vector for site $n$. How would I prove/understand this?

Comment: Checkout this [link](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/364751) for 1D case, extension to multiple dimensions is straightforward.

Comment: Thanks! Using the link, I see how this generalises to cubic lattices, but how can that be modified for arbitrary lattices?

Comment: Do you mean D-dimensional lattices with non-orthogonal basis vectors? I guess reciprocal space vectors are defined as co-orthogonal to original basis. Hence sums can be factored and hence you can proove.